# What does tsui mean in this context?

Tags: grammar

> A:「 ほんとう カンニング したん ですか。」
>
> B:「 つい。」

What does つい mean in this context?
I thought つい is used to indicate unintentionally?

Answer (score 3):

「つい」in that context means something like "Yes, in spite of myself."

> "Did you really cheat on the test?"
>
> "Yes, in spite of myself."